# How can I select rows with all Column value, which have the same values?

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to get all the courID values that have same memid values, For example, if my table looked like this (as shown in image):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT 
  memId, GROUP_CONCAT(courId) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY memId
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, it is generally appreciated to give explanations to make answers better, thus making StackOverflow better.

Answer (score 0):

Let assuming you have created you table like shown below

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  MemId INTEGER,
  CourId VARCHAR (50)
);
```

and executing insert like shown below

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '3');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '3');
```

Run query like so

```
SELECT MemId, GROUP_CONCAT( CourId) FROM test GROUP BY MemId
```

Your result should look like this

```
| MemId | GROUP_CONCAT( CourId) |
|-------|-----------------------|
|     1 |                   2,3 |
|     2 |                     2 |
|     3 |                   1,3 |
```

for further reading and understanding [see this link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)